# adding text behind mathematical solution c#

Tags: c#

//   As you can see I am trying to make this count years in work (swedish) but I want the "har du varit i arbete" to end up after the mathematical solution, I've looked at internet here and tried to read for results, but everything I've tried doesn't work. I have tried for a year, but I am new to programming and this is difficult. Could some please explain how to make this?

p.s sorry for bad eng

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication34
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool isRunning = true;

            while (isRunning)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\tVälkommen");
                Console.WriteLine("\t[1]När börja du jobba");
                string strYear = Console.ReadLine();
                int Year = Convert.ToInt32(strYear);
                Console.WriteLine(2015 - Year); // want this to end up with  
                Console.WriteLine(" Har du jobbat "); // this
                Console.WriteLine("\t[3]Avsluta");
                Console.Write("\tvälj:");
                int menyVal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                switch (menyVal)
                {
                    case 1:
                        //meddelande köras
                        break; //[1]
                    case 2:
                        isRunning = false;
                        break; //har du jobbt
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using two WriteLine() which is adding a return between the items.  You can use Write() so you don't get the return.

Comment: i will try this, thx alot i forgot that write dont give a return.

Comment: i will try this, thx alot i forgot that write dont give a return, ive tried this now "Console.Write("du har jobbat:" + 2015 - Year + "år" );" should it be. but i get the error code "- Error 1 Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'" otherwise it worked but i wanted text after that said "år = years"

Comment: Try (2015 - Year).ToString()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? 
`Console.WriteLine(2015 - Year + " " + " Har du jobbat ");`

I don't undertstand what you mean by

> how do i change my cases without going back and write "menyval ==2" etc (i want to change case 2

reason they are not on the same line is because you are calling "Console.WriteLine". That puts them on a separate line. If you want them on the same line then do something like

```
Console.WriteLine(2015 - Year + " " + "Har du jobbat " +"\t[3]Avsluta" + "\tvälj:" );
```

Comment: try this then "int Year = 2015 - Convert.ToInt32(strYear);"

Console.Write("du har jobbat:" + Year + "år");

Comment: Please do not use edits to communicate with each other; that's what comments are for!